# iOS - UIDocument Versioning

Tags: ios, objective-c, versioning, nscoding, uidocument

I want to add versioning to my UIDocument local storage setup. In each of my classes that needs to be stored locally, I overwrite `encodeWithCoder:` and `initWithCoder:` like so:

```
#define kLovelyString @"LovelyString"

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.lovelyString forKey:kLovelyString];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.lovelyString = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:kLovelyString];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I'd like to prepare for different versions of my model by adding versioning support. Should I simply add `[aCoder encodeInteger:version]` to `encodeWithCoder:` and create if/else statements in `initWithCoder:` to determine how to handle each version?

As far as I can tell, `NSFileVersion` is not helpful here.

Comment: Yeah that would be the way to do it. Just store a version that you read and handle on deserialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Dima said, this is the standard implementation. Bonus -- Best to have a global version stored in your Database Access Layer.